# how to upload file to firebase storage from a web client via firebase-admin launched with firebase-functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I am working on an admin app to be able to manage content of multiple firebase projects and I am stuck at working with firebase storage.

The flow is:

- fill the form in admin app,
- select picture to be uploaded
- invoke https callable function from firebase functions
- send image to function
- function initialize particular app
- uploads file to bucket in the firebase app

It has to be done via https callable function because I am checking against user authorization so the cloud function code starts like this:

```
export const uploadFile = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

  if (!context.auth) {
    return { error: "You are not loged in" }
  }
  if (context.auth.uid !== adminId) {
    return { error: "This user has no access to data" }
  }

  const app = admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: DBURLS[`${data.appId}-${data.env}`],
    storageBucket: STORAGEURLS[`${data.appId}-${data.env}`],
  }, `${data.appId}-${data.env}`);

  const bucket = getStorage(app).bucket();
  // What's next ???

})
```

I am a bit confused what would be the best way to send the file to firestore function. as base64 string, blob or better to open a stream.
File should be mostly an image but in some cases it can be also a video which can be a large file over 1GB.

The front end is a Ionic/React app with use of React-Dropzone for file upload.
What would be the best way, including some code samples?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I advise to use the JS SDK to [upload the image to Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) in a bucket dedicated to admin users and then call the Cloud Function that initializes a particular app and [moves](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#move) the image file to the bucket of this Firebase app.

Comment: this is good for few files but if want to upload thousands of files it may eventually double the cost.
But definitely good idea for occassional large files upload